# Multiple type inheritance in ADA via generic mixins

Tags: oop, generics, multiple-inheritance, ada

With the aim of reducing testing and repeating code I have discovered the multiple inheritance via generic mix-in but I don't know how is the best way to achieve that, as well as best practices.

Having the following class hierarchy example (done with [diagrams.net](https://www.diagrams.net)):

[image: class hierarchy]

This is the spec of the generic:

```
generic
  
  type S is abstract tagged private;

package GenericChild is
  
  type GenericChild_T is abstract new S with private;

  procedure P_SetGenericAttribute (Self : in out GenericChild_T;
                                   i    : Integer);

  function F_GetGenericAttribute (Self : GenericChild_T)
                                  return Integer;

private

  type GenericChild_T is abstract new S with
    record
      GenericAttribute : Integer;
    end record;

end GenericChild;
```

For the generic instantiation in Child1:

```
with Root;
with GenericChild;

package Child1 is
  
  type Child1_T is new Root.Root_T with private;

private

  package Child1_G is new GenericChild (Root.Root_T);

  type Child1_T is new Child1_G.GenericChild_T with null record;

end package Child1;
```

I can use the methods defined on the Root_T class without problems but, when I try to use the generic methods that is what I get:

`no selector "P_SetGenericAttribute" for private type "Child1_T" ...`

This is the main.adb where I have tested that:

```
with Child1;

procedure Main is

  Instance : Child1.Child1_T;

begin

  Instance.P_SetRootAttribute(1); --ok
  Instance.P_SetGenericAttribute(1); --illegal

end main;
```

Why? Because I have encapsulated the generic package instantiation?
In that case, how is the best way to solve it? Creating public methods in the child classes and calling the private generic instantiation methods within the method implementation? Because I would like to keep the generic instantiation as private. By doing this I'm able to set and get the attribute of the generic.

These are the changes performed to child1.ads that works for me:

```
with Root;
with GenericChild;

package Child1 is
  
  type Child1_T is new Root.Root_T with private;

  procedure P_SetGenericAttribute (Self : in out Child1_T;
                                   i    : Integer);

  function F_GetGenericAttribute (Self : Child1_T)
                                  return Integer;

private

  package Child1_G is new GenericChild (Root.Root_T);

  type Child1_T is new Child1_G.GenericChild_T with null record;

end package Child1;
```

And this is the child1.adb that completes it and works, but I'm not sure if it is a better way to achieve it, such as renaming or something else:

```
package body Child1 is

  procedure P_SetGenericAttribute (Self : in out Child1_T;
                                   i    : Integer) is
  begin
  
    Child1_G.GenericChild_T(Self).P_SetGenericAttribute (i);

  end P_SetGenericAttribute;

  function F_GetGenericAttribute (Self : Child1_T)
                                  return Integer is
  
    i : Integer;  

  begin

    i := Child1_G.GenericChild_T(Self).F_GetGenericAttribute;
    return i;

  end F_GetGenericAttribute;

end package Child1;
```

Any advice and/or best practices are welcome.

Comment: Please show the code (and its context) that provokes the "no selector" error message. Is the private part of package Child1 visible there?

Comment: @NiklasHolsti I have added the main where the error raises; this is my thinking about the error, because I have encapsulated the generic instantiation so I can't really use the generic public methods because the instantiation is private, but GNAT Studio is showing those generic methods as if they were public, and the IDE does not show the inherited ones, it is a bug.

Comment: I don't understand what, exactly, you are calling a "bug", but clearly Main does not have visibility of the private part of package Child1, therefore Main views the Instance as a descendant only of Root_T, and the operations defined in GenericChild are not visible in Main.

Comment: @NiklasHolsti the bug is in the GNAT Studio, it shows the methods for the private generic instantiation but not the inherited ones from Root_T, as you say. I thought the behaviour was ok, but I wanted confirmation about if it was caused due to the private instantiation or what, and you have confirmed it. Now, how is this problem usually solved? Because I want to encapsulate the generic instantiation but I want their public method to be usable too. Writting public methods for the type Child1_T that calls internally the generic instantiation methods works ok, but I'm not sure if is the usual way

Comment: @Albatros23 The initial answer seems: yes. If you put the instance of the generic in the private part of some package, then you'll need to add public functions to access this generic instance. However, to be able to give a more definitive answer, it would be helpful if you could add some explanatory reference to the "multiple inheritance via generic mix-in" pattern you mention and/or show the actual problem to which this pattern is to be a solution. The actual problem that this "multiple inheritance via generic mix-in" pattern solves is, at least to me, not entirely clear.

Comment: @DeeDee I have only seen pseudo code of the mix-ins, not the implementation files, so my problem is that I don't know if adding the public methods to access the generic instance is the usual way to solve the problem or if it is preferred renaming or there is any preferred solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `no selector "P_SetGenericAttribute" for private type "Child1_T" ...`

The reason you're getting this error is because your implementation (the derivation of the instantiation of GenericChild) is private; your client simply cannot see that the type *is* such a derivation.

---

But you have a bigger problem: Ada does not do multiple inheritance like you diagram. You could do multiple `interface`-types and derive from that, though. **OR** you could possibly use `generic` and static polymorphism. -- But straight-up multiple inheritance won't work. (You *can*, as you mentioned, use mix-ins as well, but those aren't really inheritance.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know that Ada is a little bit tricky to achieve a some-how multiple inheritance. I'm trying to use mix-ins within the hierarchy in order to reduce code repetition and thus testing, but I'm not sure if the way I have implemented the methods for "Child1" class is the usual way or if it is a better solution such as renaming or something else.

Comment: @Albatros23, OOP is not a good way to reduce code, what you're looking for is generics. Here's an excellent video that covers (in part) why OOP isn't a good fit for code-reuse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMPfEXIlTVE

Comment: thanks for the video. I'm agree with you, but OOP is mandatory for me unfortunately, so my aim to reduce the code using OOP is to use generic mix-ins that contains the implementation when they help to not duplicating the code.

Comment: @Albatros23, There are three papers you might be interested in on the topics of using generics-and-OOP/-mixin; though they are for Ada83 & Ada95-design:
(1) “Object-Oriented Programming Strategies for Ada”, [IDA Paper: P-3143];  
(2) “Object-Oriented Programming with Mixins in Ada”, [DOI: 10.1145/142003.142009];  
(3) “Object-Oriented Programming in Ada83 — Genericity Rehabilitated”, [DOI: 10.1145/122012.122018].